# How to import vue js components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two js file students.js and modal.js . How to import component in modal.js inside students.js?
my students.js

```
Vue.component('student', {
 data: function(){

 },
 template:`
  <h1>Click to edit students</h1>
  // use modals.js component here..........

`
})
```

my modals.js

```
Vue.component('modal', {
 template:`
 <h1>This is modal.</h1>`
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Vue.component`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Component-Names) globally registers the component so you can use it directly in any other component. Like this:

```js
Vue.component('student', {
 data: function(){

 },
 template:`
  <h1>Click to edit students</h1>
  // use modals.js component here..........
  <modal v-bind:prop="something">....</modal>  // <= focus here
`
})
```

Note: [Name your components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Full-word-component-names-strongly-recommended) according to style guide; names like `modal` is not suitable according to style guide, name it like `my-modal` where `-` should be in component name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use import. For more information : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

```js
import ComponentA from './ComponentA'
import ComponentC from './ComponentC'

export default {
  components: {
    ComponentA,
    ComponentC
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This wont apply for vue projects that use CDN setup